# Videos don't loop and seek in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, azure, html5-video

Two issues with mp4 videos hosted on Microsoft Azure in Google Chrome only:

1. Background video don't loops (implemented by vide.js)
2. Video don't seeks by vjs player.

I know, server should send video files with http status 206. But my file sends with 200 at the first time, and if it doesn't made full download, problem still remains. How to setup right sending video files on Azure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why you cannot seek within the video is caused by the storage version.
By default, the version is set to 2009-09-19. Unfortunately, this version does not support the Range Header which is required to seek within a video (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee691967.aspx). Therefore, you have to change the default version to at least 2011-08-18.

There are several way to change the default version.
From .NET you can use [CloudBlobClient.SetServiceProperties Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblobclient.setserviceproperties.aspx).

Another option is using the utility from  https://github.com/Plasma/AzureBlobUtility to change the default service version.

Also you can use the Azure REST API to set the version as documented on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh452235.aspx.
However the Authentication part is a bit tricky.